# Ulteo OVD thin client cd, thumb drive (or similar) creation?

Tags: thin-client, vdi

I am looking at the Ulteo OVD VDI solution, and hoping someone can point me to information on how to set up a bootable cd, thumb drive, or even a bootable hard drive thin client install for this platform?

I know the way it's supposed to work is you boot in to linux or windows on the client, then launch your browser and hit a url that launches the vdi session.

What I am hoping is to be able to come up with a bootable CD or thumb drive (hard drive might be acceptable if I can image it) that would have just the bare requirements/browser required, hopefully pre-configured to go to the proper URL so the user simply turns their machine on and logs in to their VDI session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want with PendriveLinux
[Pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)

Many people also use unetbootin to create a bootable USBdrive.

Remember to specify that you want a persistent file system if any tool you choose asks you.   Some assume you do, some don't.

1. Install linux on the usbdrive using one of the above.
2. Boot off that USB drive.
3. Create/add your user accounts.
4. run your web browser and go into its setup section  make the URL that points to your 
   Ulteo server the "Default" HOME PAGE.    When someone runs the browser it will also
   goto the Ulteo server login page first.
5. Create a desktop shortcut ICON for your browser and maybe rename it to be explicit as 
   to what it does.
6. Shut down your usbdrive linux system

Now all of the chances are on the USB for whoever boots it next.

There's obviously more you could do regarding setting up alot of users on the usbdrive linux system so they all get the same browser home page.   But you will have to look up how to make changes to /etc/skel on the web.

Its also rather easy to auto-launch an application like a web browser as soon as a user logs in.   So you could just boot off the USB and auto-login then auto-launch the browser which has as its home page the login display of your Ulteo server.   Just don't give the default no login user any root privileges.